# Can Perl 6 assume a positional parameter that's not the first one?

Tags: raku, currying

Perl 6 allows you to curry subroutines with [.assuming](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Callable#method_assuming). That's easy to do when you want to assume the leading positional parameters:

```
# The first one
{
sub first-and-last ( $first, $last ) {
    say "Name is $first $last";
    }

my &joe = &first-and-last.assuming( 'Joe' );

&joe.( 'Jones' );
}
```

But what if I want to assume one of the other positional parameters while leaving the first ones alone? How can I tell `.assuming` which parameters to assume?

```
# The second one
try {
sub first-and-last ( $first, $last ) {
    say "Name is $first $last";
    }

my &smith = &first-and-last.assuming( Empty, 'Smith' );

&smith.( 'Joe' );
}
```

With named parameters this is straightforward, but that's not what I'm curious about.

If this is really [just an EVAL](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=127987) underneath, that's kinda disappointing.

Comment: FWIW, there is *some* EVAL underneath at the moment, after extensive sanity checking.   But if you make sure this happens at compile time, e.g. by prefixing BEGIN, like: `my &smith = BEGIN &first-and-last.assuming( Empty, 'Smith' );` you would not suffer any de-optimization effects at runtime.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Huh, a [Whatever](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Whatever) works:

```
sub first-and-last ( $first, $last ) {
    say "Name is $first $last";
    }

my &smith = &first-and-last.assuming( *, 'Smith' );

&smith.( 'Joe' );
```

And you can handle middle parameters:

```
sub longer-names ( $first, $middle, $last, $suffix ) {
    say "Name is $first $middle $last $suffix";
    }

my &smith = &longer-names.assuming( *, *, 'Public', * );

&smith.( 'Joe', 'Q.', 'Jr.');
```

Comment: Nice examples. I liked them so much that I adapted this for the [Perl 6 docs](https://github.com/perl6/doc/pull/1296). Is this okay, or should I do my own?

Comment: Fine with me. It's all StackOverflow's license :)